# Brew install python 3.7 has not updated to location

Tags: python, pip, homebrew, python-3.7

I installed python 3.7 through `brew install python` which has offered the following response

```
==> python
Python has been installed as
  /usr/local/bin/python3

Unversioned symlinks `python`, `python-config`, `pip` etc. pointing to
`python3`, `python3-config`, `pip3` etc., respectively, have been installed into
  /usr/local/opt/python/libexec/bin

If you need Homebrew's Python 2.7 run
  brew install python@2

You can install Python packages with
  pip3 install <package>
They will install into the site-package directory
  /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

but when I call `pip3 install neo4j` it says requirement already satisfied, pointing to an earlier distribution of python:

```
 Sffd-MBP:~ Sffd$ pip3 install neo4j
Requirement already satisfied: neo4j in /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages (1.7.4)
```

indicating that homebrew has not unversioned symlinks. What is the best way to do this manually and does anyone know why this has not happened automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you have to install it again.
run:

pip3 uninstall neo4j

pip3 install neo4j

Comment: no because it is linking to python 3.5.2 not python 3.7

Comment: try: python3.7 -m pip install neo4j

Comment: unfortunately does not exist

Comment: but the interpreter does on pycharm, the interpreter is there

Comment: if you type python3.7 in your command Line, what does it say ?

Comment: or try typing: python --version

Comment: -bash: python3.7: command not found
python3 --version
Python 3.5.1

Comment: this link should help you: https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/